# matlab - creating one figure from 2 different figures

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, subplot

I have 2 different figures. One of them is an empty template with logos, a kind of a background. The other one is the existing subplots. The question is, how can I make matlab generate the subplots on this empty template figure with logos ?

```
 tempfigure1 = figure('PaperType','A4','PaperSize',[29.7 21],'PaperOrientation', 'landscape',...
                 'Color',[1 1 1],'Units', 'centimeters','Position',[2 2 29.7 21]);
% The code continues like this with tempfigure1
```

A part of the other figure is created with this code:

```
 subplot(tempPosition{tempCNT,1},tempPosition{tempCNT,2},tempPosition{tempCNT,3});
%all temp*s are already defined before this line
```

With those codes, matlab gives me 2 different figures that I don't need. After creating them both in a figure I would like to export it as pdf with this following code which just exports one of the figures :

```
  print(gcf, '-dpdf', 'output.pdf');
```

I appreciate your help !

Regards,

Tolga

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for the [hold](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/hold.html) command. There you can hold a figure to do all the plotting in. For instance:

```
figure(1)
hold on % Tell MatLab to plot everything in this figure

plot(1:10,1:10,'-r') % Plot a red line
plot(1:10,2:11,'-g') % Plot a green line

hold off
```

Then export your figure as you proposed:

```
print(gcf, '-dpdf', 'output.pdf');
```

Good luck!